# Blank column separates two variables in wide format

Tags: r, tidyr, data-wrangling

I am tidying the [Quarterly Employment Statistics](http://www.statssa.gov.za/?page_id=1854&PPN=P0277) dataset that Statistics South Africa provides. The [Excel file](http://www.statssa.gov.za/publications/P0277/QES_Details_BreakDown_200909_202003.xlsx) is just aggregated data.

Two variables (employment levels and aggregate earnings) are in wide format, with the data spanning quarters over time. Row 1 in the Excel file gives the variable names, and row 2 gives the quarters. The two variables are separated by a blank column, but the quarter values are the same. I am happy to ignore row 1, and instead set row 2 as the "names", however, the quarter values are repeated between the two variables, so I need to rename the columns.

Instead of writing code to tidy the current dataset (hard-coding in a numerical vector for the columns to rename), I want to write code that will tidy all future updated datasets, where I expect that each new quarter for `employees` will be added just before the blank column. The following code imports the dataset correctly at present. Please tell me how I can rather select the columns to rename based on the blank column separation.

```
QES <- read_xlsx(
        path="QES.xlsx",
        range=cell_limits(c(2, 1), c(115, NA))
    ) %>%
    rename(
        industry=...1,
        SIC=...2
    ) %>%
    rename_with(
        .fn=function(q) paste("employees", q, sep="."),
        .cols=seq(3, 45, 1)     # '45' will change every quarter.
    ) %>%
    rename_with(
        .fn=~substr(x=., start=1, stop=16),
        .cols=starts_with("employees.")
    ) %>%
    rename_with(
        .fn=function(q) paste("earnings", q, sep="."),
        .cols=seq(47, 89, 1)    # '47' and '89' will change every quarter.
    ) %>%
    rename_with(
        .fn=~substr(x=., start=1, stop=15),
        .cols=starts_with("earnings.")
    ) %>%
    select(-46) %>%     # blank column
    pivot_longer(
        cols=-c(1, 2),
        names_to=c(".value", "time"),
        names_pattern="(.+).([0-9]{6})"
    ) %>%
    mutate( time=as.yearmon(time, "%Y%m") )
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4,859 x 5
   industry             SIC   time      employees    earnings
   <chr>                <chr> <yearmon>     <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 Mining and quarrying 2     Sep 2009     487132 16448188825
 2 Mining and quarrying 2     Dec 2009     487745 17510873008
 3 Mining and quarrying 2     Mar 2010     490847 17149708859
 4 Mining and quarrying 2     Jun 2010     496710 17603372833
 5 Mining and quarrying 2     Sep 2010     505244 19129235237
 6 Mining and quarrying 2     Dec 2010     504067 19696688896
 7 Mining and quarrying 2     Mar 2011     511433 19567627283
 8 Mining and quarrying 2     Jun 2011     517104 20444707224
 9 Mining and quarrying 2     Sep 2011     518719 21593220480
10 Mining and quarrying 2     Dec 2011     518240 24878861928
# ... with 4,849 more rows
```

Comment: Have you tried rename_at?

Comment: @Florian I see that `rename_at()` is [superseded](https://www.tidyverse.org/lifecycle/#superseded). The main challenge in my question is the `.cols` argument in `rename_with()`.